# About solving an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I want to prove this inequality:

$$(\ln2^{t}).\ln(\ln2^{t})-2^{t+1}+1<0$$

for all $t>0$.

But I have no a good idea to start.

Comment: I would start by remembering that $2^t = e^{t \ln{2}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: put $x=\ln (2^{t})$. The question reduces to showing that $x\ln\,x -2e^{x}+1 <0$ for $x >0$. Show that the derivative is negative (using the series expansion of $e^{x}$) and that the inequality holds at $x=0$.

Comment: $t>0$ implies $2^{t} >1$ so $x >0$.

Comment: We can do it without using the series expansion. It is sufficient to show that the maximum value of the first derivative is negative. The second derivative cancels at $x=W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.351734$ for which the first derivative is $\approx -2.88794$ and the third derivative being always negative, this is a maximum value.